# JAX-RS Bind implementation of generic type in ApplicationBinder

Tags: java, generics, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Is it possible to bind a class with type parameters in an implementation of an AbstractBinder?

Generic repository class
`public class Repository<T>{ ... }`

Service class

```
public class AccountService{  

     Repository<User> repository;  

     @Inject  
     public AccountService(Repository<User> repository){  
        this.repository = repository;
     }

}
```

Bind generic repository in binder

```
public class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {

@Override
protected void configure() {  
      bind(Repository<User,Long>).to(Repository<User,Long>.class); <=== not working!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`TypeLiteral`](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/TypeLiteral.html)

> Supports inline instantiation of objects that represent parameterized types with actual type parameters. An object that represents any parameterized type may be obtained by subclassing `TypeLiteral`.
>
> ```
> TypeLiteral<List<String>> stringListType = new TypeLiteral<List<String>>() {};
> ```

And instead of `bind`, you would need to use [`bindAsContract(TypeLiteral)`](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/AbstractBinder.html#bindAsContract%28org.glassfish.hk2.api.TypeLiteral%29), as there is not `bind` method that accepts a `TypeLiteral`<sup>[**1**]</sup>.

```
bindAsContract(new TypeLiteral<Repository<User, Long>>(){});
```

---

<sup>[**1**] - See more in [`AbstractBinder`](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/AbstractBinder.html) docs.</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This did the job. I don't understand the difference between the explanations from the docs:   bind: Start building a new class-based service binding. Does NOT bind the service type itself as a contract type. bindAsContract: Start building a new class-based service binding. Binds the service type itself as a contract type.

Comment: It usually goes `bind( service ).to( contract )`, where the `contract` is normally the same or super type. With `bindAsContract`, you skip the `to( contract )`, but the limitation is that the advertised contract is the same as the service type, as opposed to doing `bind( SubType.class ).to( SuperType.class)`, it's more like `bind( Type.class ).to( Type.class )`